# Why does string.match(...)[0] throws an exception?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm trying to pull the first occurence of a regex pattern from a string all in one statement to make my code look cleaner. This is what I want to do:

```
var matchedString = somestring.match(/some regex/g)[0];
```

I would expect this to be legal but it throws an exception:

```
Exception: somestring.match(...) is null
```

It seems like JS is trying to index the array before match is finsihed, as the array does provide atleast one match, so I don't expect it to be null.

I would like some insight in why it happens. Could it be a bug?

My machine is a PC running Arch Linux x86_64. The code is being executed within the scratchpad of firefox 32.0.3.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Because the regex didn't match. That statement works just fine if it does match.

Comment: @naf456: Please do provide the real values, otherwise it's impossible to reproduce.

Comment: The regex matches - I know this because I reference an array index on a line below it and it works - it finds the string and thus is not null. I now recognise that it is in fact dangerous to write this (what if the string really IS null - an exception with be thrown.) And so you guys have indeed helped me somewhat. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it really doesn't match? I put through 900 or so `somestring`'s ~200 of which **don't** actually match. Oh, it's all coming to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `somestring.match()` finds no match, then it returns `null`.

And, `null[0]` throws an exception.

Since you are getting this exact exception, your regex is not being found in the content.  Be very careful using the `g` flag on a match option in this way as it does not always do what you expect when you have submatches specified in the regex.  Since it looks like you just want the first match anyway, you should probably remove the `g` option.

---

A safer way to code is:

```
var matches = somestring.match(/some regex/);
if (matches) {
    // do something here with matches[0]
}
```

Comment: Agree - it is dangerous to reference the array index immediately as we do not know if it's null or not, that is, unless we *expect* there to be a match. Still, in my case, I want to avoid commonly using try catch statements. Apologies from the level of question, I haven't spent a tremendous time working with code!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one statement (and there's no particularly good reason why that is a good idea, see jfriend000's answer), then:

```
var firstMatchOrFalse = /pattern/.test(somestring) && somestring.match(/pattern/)[0];
```

and if you only want the first match, why the *g* flag?

Comment: I use the g flag because it produces a more simpler object then without it (I have forgotten the name of the return type.)

Comment: @naf456—the *g* only affects how many matches are returned if there is more than one match, otherwise it has no effect.