# Looking for if null ignore - Regular Expressions - TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, google-apps-script

I found a lot of threads for this topic but none seems to answer how to ignore code if this error occurs.
I'm currently trying to get around it by using an IF statement. I'm looking for Error handling as this could always happen with my search. I know why I have this error so no explanation is needed there.

```
  var regExpQ = /Depending_Invoice_(\d{6})_/
  if (egExpQ.exec(file_name)[1] != null) {

    var invoice_date = RegExp.exec(file_name)[1];
    temp_cell_invoice_date.setValue(invoice_date)
  }
```

Comment: `RegExp` is already a build-in class, choose an other name.

Comment: `var m = /Depending_Invoice_(\d{6})_/.exec(file_name)` and then `if (m) { .... }`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I updated my question regarding this. Thanks for the Tipp but this didn't caused the problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't work as this does exacly the same       `var regExpQ = /Depending_Invoice_(\d{6})_/
      var invoice_date = RegExp.exec(file_name);
      
      if (invoice_date) {
        
        temp_cell_invoice_date.setValue(invoice_date[1])
      }` just tried it again

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't get it to work with your suggestion

Comment: See [demo](https://tio.run/##Zcy9CsIwFIbhvVdxtiagKfWnS3HTwdFZJYT0tETyU9JQAqXXHiOIi9/6vTwvMYtJejWGrXUdpjQLDx6HSxxvcILqjCPaTtmBX@3slEROHt3SrJRXG@iVRm6FwVyW/2W92x@ODQ8sxFC2xUc2ufzqDCNK8iNoW6geiKGwFJAnnZ2cRqbdQMy9fuZ/TekN). See [a linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26415226/3832970).

Comment: Your trying to dereference an oblect that is null. When do this `[1]` the object must exist before the overload `[]` func can be called. Change to `if (egExpQ.exec(file_name) != null)` or just `if (egExpQ.exec(file_name) )`. Why care about group 1, if match it always contain sumthig

Comment: @Edward I knew that I'm trying to access and object that is null but it seems like the mistake was by trying to check if `file_name[1] != null` as the rest of the code worked. What I didn't know was that match [0] always contains something when using RegEx. Thanks for that information, this helped me to understand the solution! I was a bit irritated by the fact that even if I declared `var file_name = ["", ""]` before using RegEx it failed with my approach.

Comment: file_name is expected to be a string. If it's array might take first element. But, the exception is because of `null[1]` not anything else. C++ equivalent is `(*pobj)[1]` where pobj = NULL.